# Create 2D Spectrogram in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, latex, tikz, spectrogram

I am in need of plotting a 2D spectrogram of a signal in Matlab. I need it for a printed assignment, hence the 3D image makes no sense. However, when the signal is plotted using `Spectrogram` it automatically produces a 3D plot of the signal.

My Code:

```
Dataset     = 1;            % Dataset to be analysed
N           = 1024;         % Window size
Beta        = 12;           % Kaiser window beta value (small = narrow main lope)
Overlap     = 800;          % Window overlap
Threshold   = -150;         % Minimum magnitude before threshold

spectrogram(Enclosure{Dataset}(1:end),kaiser(N,Beta),Overlap,2048,fs,'MinThreshold',Threshold,'yaxis');
```

which produces a graph that looks like this:

[image: 2D Plot]

But it is seen from the top, and the graph is really showing this:

[image: 3D plot]

The reason why i need it to specifically be 2D (and why i don't settle with a screenshot) is because i am using `Matlab2tikz` to convert Matlab figures into Tikz figures in LaTex. with the 3D images i get figures of +100 Mb and 2D will reduce the size to <1Mb.

Comment: why not make a 2D plot directly with the outputs of the function, e.g. S = spectrogram(). Then use S to make your plot.

Comment: It might be possible. I just can't figure out how to handle the output from the `spectrogram` function. The axis are no where near the correct and when plotted it shows some strange plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what version of Matlab you are using but in 2015a you should be able to get a handle to the figure with the 3D plot and change the view angle to 2D:

```
view(0,90);
```

I've also got an example of how you can make your own 2D plot from the outputs of spectrogram() using a similar method:

```
x = [0:0.01:100];
y = sin(5*x);
y = awgn(y,0.1);

[S,F,T,P] = spectrogram(y,200,0,length(y)*5,100);

[m,n] = size(P);

figure(2)
surf(F,T,zeros(n,m),P','EdgeColor','none')
view(0,90)
xlabel('Frequency')
ylabel('Time (s)')
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Hopefully since there is no altitude information, the figure size might be smaller but I can't test that since I don't have Matlab2tikz.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to capture whatever its plotted and then plot it as an image. You can do this using [`getframe`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html)

if you do

```
F=getframe(gca);
cla;
imshow(F.cdata);
```

You'll get exactly what you will be seeing before, but as an image.

However I think it defeats a bit the purpose of Matlab2Tikz, as the idea os that you have Tikz code describing your data...

Comment: Yeah, and the whole point of this question were to find a solution where i could get a usable Tikz output.

Comment: @MikkelKroghSimonsen My point is: If you make the plot 2d (the same as making it an image) you loose the data. So either you have the 3D version in TIKz, or you make a 2D version without information.  This answer does the same thing than willpower's answer, just the data will be saved with different values. Unless you are going to fiddle with the numbers manually in the TIKz output code, this should work

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
[~,F,T,ps]=spectrogram(Enclosure{Dataset}(1:end),kaiser(N,Beta),Overlap,2048,fs,'MinThreshold',Threshold,'yaxis').
% Output the spectrum in ps

imagesc(T,F,10*log10(ps)) 
% Generate a 2d image

view(270,90)
xlabel('Time [s]')
ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
c=colorbar;
c.Label.String='Power [dB]';
% Extra setting to make the plot look like the spectrogram
```

Good luck